# Gridview : How to make the header text multiline?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

The default header text for each column is for a single line. Is there any way of making the header *multiline so I can add another line of text under the first one.?

Thanks

Comment: You can add a <br />.  The header supports html.

Comment: Jax - be sure to mark Jeremy's answer as the answer so he gets appropriate rep points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thanks , it worked !

For the sake of closure, I'll add my comment here:

You can add a `<br />`. The header supports html.

Comment: I just found out you can make it work for BoundField columns if you add `HtmlEncode="false"` to your BoundField :)